# Usage of "so far"

Tags: grammar

I have a question regarding usage of **"so far"**. Can anyone please tell me whether I have used ***so far*** in my sentence correctly?

Here's the example sentence:

- John, you have done many wrong things in your life. I have supported you every time and have been with you ***so far*** but from now on I will never support you.

Answer (score 1):

I would place **"so far"** in a different section, as to me it sounds a bit weird saying it out loud.  My update sentence would be this:

> John, you have done many wrong things in your life.  **So far**, I have supported you every time and have been with you, but from now on I will never support you.

---

The definition of **so far** from [Google dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=so+far+definition&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS796US796&oq=so+far+definition&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.1871j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) states that the definition is "*(of a trend that seems likely to continue) up to this time*".  Up to this time, you have been supporting John, but now you won't be.

An expanded meaning of your statement would be:

> **Up to this time**, I have supported you every time...

Again, this is my personal recommendation from my perspective as a native speaker.  Your sentence would still technically work, but I find it sounds cleaner with this version.

Comment: Or you could use "Up to now, ..."

Comment: @user3169 Yea, I could have, but I was using the previous definition I stated for continuity.